# How to use wrapper with beforeEach and afterEach?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Every test I made with jest it's begining with `await app.transaction(async(trx) => {` and ends with `..rollback..`

```
await app.transaction(async(trx) => {
 
 const a = await update();

 expect(a).toBe(something);

 await trx.rollback();   

});
```

The actual test is:

```
 const a = await update();
 expect(a).toBe(something);
```

And I want instead of write this wrapper for every test function, just to write within the `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.

Comment: What kind of a transaction do you use?

Comment: knexjs for sql. the actions must be inside the function in order to make transaction to work.

Comment: So there is no way to define a transaction object explicitly and use it afterwards to either commit or rollback a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Since the test is inside of the parameter to `transaction` you can't really do this in a `beforeEach` since it will differ based on the test. However you can avoid duplicating the code in each test by writing a helper function like this:

```js
async function wrapper(testFn) {
  return app.transaction(async(trx) => {
    await testFn();
    return trx.rollback();
  }
}

// then do this in each test:
it('should work', () => {
  await wrapper(async () => {
    const a = await update();
    expect(a).toBe(something);
  });
});
```